# Visual Studio shaping buttons and textbox key

Tags: winforms, button, textbox, keyboard

I'm using Visual studio 2010 WinForms and I'm designing my UI when I met my problems. The buttons provided in the tools are always rectangular shaped and looks boring, is there a way to change the shape of the button? To like circle or oval?

Another question, how can I enable the keyboard 'Enter' button to be used in the TextBox?
For exmaple: I typed in an address into the TextBox and when I press 'Enter', I want it to do something.

Please advice, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Winforms, in general, is about using stock objects, so Buttons are rectangle, drawn in the system style of the operating system.  You can look at 3rd party controls for fancier buttons,  make your own custom control button, or look at developing in [WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx), which allows for much more "skinnable" type user interfaces.

As far as the `TextBox` 'Enter' key, you would have to catch that in the KeyDown event:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
  if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) {
    // do something
  }
}
```